# A suggested edit keeps coming up over and over again …

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

A suggested edit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18027682/1456376) keeps coming up in the review list of suggested edits:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3064062
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3064164
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3064206
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3064235

Is this a bug or is the user constantly submitting the edit over and over again? And as a follow up question: How to deal with it?

Comment: Maybe it's a new "Is the reviewer awake?" test. :)

Comment: It's the same editor, you can see that in their profile http://stackoverflow.com/users/2829228/user2829228?tab=activity - repeated edits.

Comment: @Mat Ah cool, I didn't know, I can see *other* user's profile with so much detail. That keeps the question: How to deal with it?

Comment: Does protecting it protect against suggested edits?

Comment: @fedorqui: protection does nothing for edits. insertname: nothing, the edit ban will kick in shortly.

Comment: @Mat Thanks, I see, there's such a thing like a ban for this behavior. Your two comments will make up an "acceptable" answer I guess. ;)

Comment: The edit sort of looks like the editor thought that it was his own answer and wanted to add code to it. Perhaps he should be advised to make a new answer with his code?

Comment: @Amber This is exactly what I did twice: Rejecting the edit with a custom message encouraging the editor to submit an answer of his own.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first edit is slightly different from the rest in content; it appears his second edit was really a modification to his first, and it was submitted after it was initially rejected (unbeknownst to him).

That said, his [fifth attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3064265) has been rejected and he should be edit-banned by now. Hopefully he got the hint, but if he comes back in 7 days and tries to edit the answer again, you can flag it and I'll talk to him, and lock the post if it really has to come to that.

He does not appear to be the author of the answer, just some unregistered fellow who probably hasn't learned the ropes.